# Kohana 3 ORM retrieve last insert ID

Tags: orm, kohana, kohana-3, lastinsertid

Is there a way after the ->save() call to get the last insert id?

Example Code:

```
$post_data = $_POST;
$user = ORM::factory('user');
$user->username = $post_data['username'];
$user->email = $post_data['email'];
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, assuming your insert code looked like this:

```
$user = ORM::factory('user')->values($post)->save();
```

To get the last insert ID simply do this after the call to `->save()`

```
echo $user->id;
```

In your case you would need to do `$user->user_id` as you've named your primary key `user_id`.

I would alternatively recommend biakaveron's advice to instead use [`$user->pk()`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#pk) as it will always return the value of the primary key regardless of the name given to it, provided that you specify the primary key name in your model with `$_primary_key`.

The model will be populated with the saved values ready for reuse if the insert worked.

Job done!

Comment: I updated my question... and $user->id gives me an error.

**The id property does not exist in the Model_User class**

.  But I am able to get the last insert id by calling `$user->pk()`.

Comment: Does your user table have a primary key named `id`?

Comment: My Model User table:
`Class Model_User extends ORM
{

  protected $_primary_key = 'user_id';


}`

Comment: Thats why you should always use `->pk()` instead of `->id`

Answer (score 1):

Just call `$model->id;` - ORM will do the last insert id inclusion for you.